# How do I target @Model within a src of an image tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Like the question says I can't manage to target the `@Model` within a `src` part of an `image` tag.

```
<dt>
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
</dt>
<dd><img src="~/Content/EmployeeImages@Model.ImageUrl" alt="Employee Photo" /></dd>
```

Everything but this is wired up correctly but when I try to call `@Model` it becomes part of the reference, instead of throwing the `GUID` in there like it's supposed to.
Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Surely it should just be `src="@Model.ImageUrl"`?

Comment: What you have should work, what actually get's output?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<dt>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
</dt>
<dd>
    <img src="@("~/Content/EmployeeImages" + Model.ImageUrl)" alt="Employee Photo" />
</dd>
```

Comment: This will only work is limited cases.   Normally `<img src="~..` will have the `~` expanded by Razor to the root of you website.  If you put it in a literal like this, it will be sent as-is and not expanded.  If your website has any sort of sub-path to the root of the website, this won't work.

Comment: @freedomn-m  seem you have not read issue / Question. I just mention how can overcome from this issue.

Comment: Just advising that this will not create a working `src` value in all cases (I tried it first to be sure).  It will put the `Model.ImageUrl` in the src attribute, which could be argued is the base requirement, but the image itself won't be shown as I explained.  You'll note I didn't give a downvote, just added additional information.

Comment: @freedomn-m appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `@String.Format`:

I know that you may not want to generate an image like I have but the idea to use `@String.Format` should still work for you.

```
<img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64, {0}", Model.CompanyLogo)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
src="@(String.Format("{0} {1}", "~/Content/EmployeeImages", Model.BackgroundColor))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I put everything inside of a folder named EmployeeImages and removed the EmployeeImages prefix from the images, as well as adding an additional slash in the src after employeeImages to designate it as another folder. Now it properly displays the guid. Sorry for wasting your guys' time, spent an hour struggling with it last night.